# How to present view controller from UILabel with tap gesture recognized in custom table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a custom dynamic table view cell with a label that has a tap gesture recognized added. When the user taps the label, not anywhere else in the cell, I want to present a view controller.

The instagram app has this feature. Ie. when you tap likes, it takes you to a likes table view, when you tap comments, it shows you to a comments table view. This is the same experience I want.

I am not looking to use didSelectRow because then it kind of defeats the purpose of having the specific target area to tap to show a new view controller.

*So, how can I present a view controller from a tap gesture recognizer in a subclass of UITableViewCell?*

UPDATED:

I am passing a closure to my custom TableViewCell which is successfully being called when the button is pressed.  But I am stuck in the TableView and cannot pass information to the next View Controller I want to present.  And I can't actaully perform the segue either :\

```
// From UITableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let story = stories[indexPath.row]
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Fun Cell", for: indexPath) as? FunTableViewCell {

        cell.configureCell(title: story.title, info: story.info)

        cell.buttonAction = { [weak self] (cell) in
                print("the button was pressed for \(story.title)")
            self?.buttonWAsTapped(title: story.title)
        }
        return cell
    } else {
        return FunTableViewCell()
    }
}

func buttonWAsTapped(title: String) {
    // Need to pass something to the next View Controller... but how??? 

    if let nextVC = UIViewController() as? DetailViewController {
        nextVC.storyTitle = title
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "Button Pressed", sender: self)
    }
} 


// Custom TableViewCell
class FunTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var funLabel: FunLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var standardLabel: TappedLabel!
@IBOutlet weak var funButton: FunButton!

var buttonAction: ((UITableViewCell) -> Void)?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(readMoreTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    standardLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    standardLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}

@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    print("Button pressed")
    buttonAction?(self)
}
```

Comment: Doable for sure. What's the question?

Comment: How do I present a view controller from a tap gesture recognized in a reusable table view cell?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the cell, pass a block to it. That's the handler for the `button`.
When the button tapped, call the block.
You can save the block as a property of the subclass of `UITableViewCell`.

In your tableViewCell class, add a property:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    open var completionHandler: (()->Void)?

}
```

In your viewController that has the tableView:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = CustomTableViewCell()
    cell.completionHandler = {
        () -> Void in
        let newViewController = UIViewController()
        //configure the VC here base on the indexPath
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am looking to do this in a uilabel with a tap gesture recognized, not a UIButton. Also, could you explain or share a code sample of what you mean by pass it a block?

Comment: @BrianGlowe A label with tap gesture recognizer is pretty much a button. And in swift, block is called closure.

Comment: Okay that's fair about the label and gesture recognizer. I'm trying to wrap my head around how I will present a view controller from the closure . I apologize this is new to me and I appreciate your help.

Comment: @BrianGlowe Let's say in the `cellForRowAt` method, you need to create the cell for the row. After creating the cell, you can give it a block. I will write some sample code for you.

Comment: Thanks alot @jokeman  I have successfully passed a closure to the custom cell thanks to your guidance.  But I can't seem to pass any info to the next View Controller or actually perform the segue.  I have updated my question with the code I am using.  Can you tell me what I am missing or doing wrong that is not allowing me to segue?

Comment: @BrianGlowe If you want to configure your nextViewController, you should do it in `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`. In the `performSeque` method, you don't need to pass your nextVC right? That's saying, the configure you did won't work at all

Comment: Okay so how would that work?: if I call performSegue from  buttonWAsTapped(_:) and then in prepareForSegue I will prepare the DetailVC with the data I need to pass. But how do I tell prepareForSegue I need to share the info from the button pressed?

Comment: @BrianGlowe No need to use performSegue. Just use presentViewController if you want to present modally. Or use self.navigationController.pushViewController if you want to push the new VC into the navigationController stack

Comment: @BrianGlowe I think it's not necessary to pass the cell into the closure. You can use a `() -> Void` closure with no problem

Comment: @BrianGlowe you code `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(readMoreTapped))`, do you really have the method `readMoreTapped` in the tableViewCell subclass?

Comment: yes I do have the readMoreTapped() but it was added to the label. And as I worked through your suggestions I used a button instead to make it more simple. I could have removed the tap gesture from the code sample